# Connecting a viewcontroller to a delegate class - CLLocationManager / iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, delegates

While trying to link my view controller to a delegate class (that implements CLLocation call backs), I am getting an error when initializing my delegate.

My VC.h:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <MyLocationControllerDelegate> {
  MyLocationController *CLController;
}
```

Instantiating MyLocationController in the main VC.m:

CLController = [[MyLocationController alloc] init];
  CLController.locationManager.delegate = self;
  [CLController.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
  CLController.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
  CLController.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
  [CLController.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

The class header file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@protocol MyLocationControllerDelegate;

@interface MyLocationController: NSObject {
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
   __weak id delegate;

}

@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property (nonatomic, weak) id delegate;

@end
```

and .m file (where I get the error):

```
- (id)init 
{
    self = [super init];

    if(self != nil) {
        self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init]; // Create new instance of locationManager
        self.locationManager.delegate = self; // Set the delegate as self.

    }

    return self;
}
```

I noticed that this error does not show up in previous iOS versions.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks for the edits @jeffery! No idea how to do that yet..

Comment: Your protocol declaration is empty. Where is your MyLocationControllerDelegate defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLLocationManager/delegate), `MyLocationController` must conform to `CLLocationManagerDelegate`.

```
@interface MyLocationController: NSObject <CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property (nonatomic, weak) id delegate;

@end
```

As a side note, you don't need to declare the iVars for the properties `locationManager` and `delegate`. The iVars `_locationManager` and `_delegate` will be auto generated for you.

Comment: Thanks, that did it! Side question, from some reason I dont get any call backs when the call back function didUpdateLocations: is in a separate class. Any idea what could have gone wrong? I updated my description with more info for context. thanks for the help!